# Git server allowing pull and push without private key

Tags: git

On a Ubuntu 12.04 machine, I installed git-server following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-git-server-on-a-vps

Even after adding the pub keys to the authorized_keys file, anyone without the private key is able to clone and push new commits to the server. What could possibly cause this issue?

Comment: Are they using a ssh url like `git@git.droplet.com:user1/user-project.git` ?

Comment: Yes @VonC, the URL used is in the same format as your example.

Comment: Hello, any feedback on my answer, please? You do seem to need help if you put a bounty on the question. But then it makes sense to also comment on answers so as to make it clear whether you need more information or not. Thank you.

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that anyone without the private key is able to clone/push to the server? Is it possible you have [SSH Agent Forwarding](https://developer.github.com/guides/using-ssh-agent-forwarding/) enabled and your test session has been "poisoned" with the proper credentials?

Comment: Also the tutorial you linked is pretty bad. Assuming you followed it word for word, you'd have problems with the permissions on the `~/.ssh` folder and `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` (they should be 700 and 600 respectively). Verify those permissions and let's go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a verbose trace of your ssh connection by using a small script and defining GIT_SSH so that this script is used when git connects to your server.

```
#!/bin/sh
exec ssh -v $@
```

and `export GIT_SSH=$HOME/ssh-debug` or whatever you call this file. The **`-v`** flag turns on verbose messages from ssh and you can see which stage allows a connection. In testing this against my server here I can see it attempt to load various keys then ask for a password to unlock the keyfile. If I give a bad password it goes on to try password login on the server. Possibly you have allowed password login with an empty password on the `git` account which then authorizes anyone. However, I reckon verbose logging the ssh connection should reveal the problem.

The above script works with windows clients too. Just use `set GIT_SSH=c:\pathwithoutspace\ssh-debug` if you use the cmd shell.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your SSH server permits logins with user name and password. It can be disabled [like this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring#Disable_Password_Authentication), i.e. via `PasswordAuthentication no` in *sshd_config* on the server.

**Update:** Many people think there is something like "Git administration". Usually there is no such thing. Git administration mostly consists of SSH deamon configuration and whatever kind of config the SSH server has is just utilised by Git whenever the SSH protocol is used.

Comment: If he is using the format git@git.droplet.com:user1/user-project.git, it would only be the git user, so unless it's prompting him for a password and he is entering it during the push/pull, that would only complicate things.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Obviously the OP wants to prohibit push without permitted private key and specifically prohibit user/pw logins. My answer explains how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You're disabling SSH with password for all users. If he is using standard git SSH formatting, it just SSHs with the git user, and unless for some reason he is typing in the git user's password when pushing/pulling, this will do nothing but disable SSH for any other users that may be using a password.